# IOS8 Device Specific Font in storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard

In one of the views in my app, I want to use different font sizes for different device sizes. Since iPhone 5 and iPhone 6+ are in the same size class (when in portrait mode), I cannot solve this problem by size class. (If I override the size class methods to put iPhone 6+ into another class, iPad will not display correctly).

I know I can specify font sizes in code, but is there any way to do it in storyboard? So that I can preview the view in assistant editor.

Comment: This answer might help you to solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/58994840/9204192

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe there is a different way to do this in storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your case . you need to identify the user device modal.

```
enum DeviceModals : String {
    //iphones
    case iPhone5s_GSM = "iPhone6,1"
    case iPhone5s_China_Gobal = "iPhone6,2"
    case iPhone6_Plus = "iPhone7,1"
    case iPhone6 = "iPhone7,2"
    case iPhone6S = "iPhone8,1"
    case iPhone6S_Plus = "iPhone8,2"
    case iPhoneSE = "iPhone8,4"
    case iPhone7_CDMA = "iPhone9,1"
    case iPhone7_GSM = "iPhone9,3"
    case iPhone7_Plus_CDMA = "iPhone9,2"
    case iPhone7_Plus_GSM = "iPhone9,4"
    case iPhone_8_CDMA =   "iPhone10,1"
    case iPhone_8_GSM =  "iPhone10,4"
    case iPhone_8_Plus_CDMA =  "iPhone10,2"
    case iPhone_8_Plus_GSM =  "iPhone10,5"
    case iPhone_X_CDMA = "iPhone10,3"
    case iPhone_X_GSM =  "iPhone10,6"
    case iPhone_XS = "iPhone11,2"
    case iPhone_XS_Max =   "iPhone11,4"
    case iPhone_XS_Max_China = "iPhone11,6"
    case iPhone_XR =   "iPhone11,8"
    case iPhone_11 =   "iPhone12,1"
    case iPhone_11_Pro =  "iPhone12,3"
    case iPhone_11_Pro_Max =  "iPhone12,5"

    //iPad
   case iPad_Air_wifi_5Gen  =  "iPad4,1"
   case iPad_Air_cellular_5Gen =  "iPad4,2"
   case iPad_Mini_wifi_2Gen = "iPad4,4"
   case iPad_Mini_cellular_2Gen = "iPad4,5"
   case iPad_Mini_wifi_3rd_Gen =  "iPad4,7"
   case iPad_Pro_12_9_A1584 =  "iPad6,7"
   case iPad_Pro_12_9_A1652 =  "iPad6,8"
   case iPad_Pro_9_7_A1673 =  "iPad6,3"
   case iPad_Pro_9_7_A1674 =  "iPad6,4"

    case otherDevice = "other"

}
extension UIDevice {
    var modelName: String {
        var systemInfo = utsname()
        uname(&systemInfo)
        let machineMirror = Mirror(reflecting: systemInfo.machine)
        let identifier = machineMirror.children.reduce("") { identifier, element in
            guard let value = element.value as? Int8, value != 0 else { return identifier }
            return identifier + String(UnicodeScalar(UInt8(value)))
        }
        return identifier
    }
    func deviceModal() -> DeviceModals{
        let deviceName  = UIDevice.current.modelName
        let deviceModal = DeviceModals(rawValue: deviceName) ?? DeviceModals.otherDevice
        return deviceModal
    }
}
```

If you support the Accessibility feature in your app. Users will have a controller for text Size in your app.

Settings -> Display&brightness -> Text Size .

This default size will change for different devices based on device size.

```
    extension UIFont
    {
    // A scale value based on the current device text size setting.    With the device using the default Large setting, `scaler` will be `1.0`. Only used when `UIFontMetrics` is not available.
        var scaler: CGFloat {
            return UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle:.body).pointSize/17.0
         }
       func scaledFont() -> UIFont {
            if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
                return UIFontMetrics.default.scaledFont(for: self)
            } else {
                return self.withSize(scaler * self.pointSize)
            }
        }
    }
```

You can button font now.

```
UILabel().font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12).scaledFont()
```

Now you knew which device users have, So you can create one custom Label (or) Button (or) AnyComponent with text data.

```
class CustomLabel : UILabel{

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        let deviceModal = UIDevice.current.deviceModal()
        var font_size : CGFloat = 18
        switch deviceModal {
        case .iPhone5s_GSM , .iPhone5s_China_Gobal  :
            font_size = 12
        case .iPhone_8_Plus_CDMA , .iPhone_8_Plus_GSM:
           font_size = 18
        case .iPhone_XR:
            font_size = 19
        default:
            font_size = 18
        }
        self.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: font_size).scaledFont()
    }
}
```

In your storyboard select your label, go to the right corner and select custom class and put "CustomLabel".Now you don't have to write any other code it will work perfectly.

[image]

I hope your issue is solved now.